# disabling loging prompt over splash screen embedded linux

Tags: linux, embedded, splash-screen

I have added a full screen splash screen (just replacing image.ppm file by my ppm file)on embedded board and it is working well. but after splash screen i am getting FB login messages and login prompt as well. suggest me to disable this login on Display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disable getty in `/etc/inittab`**

Open the `/etc/inittab` file on the target filesystem, locate the lines that look like this (some numbers might be different)

```
1:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty1
```

and disable them, by putting a `#` character in front of them

```
#1:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty1
```

If you have a serial port on the board, and there is a similar line belonging to that port (it can be recognized by a slightly different device name at the end), then don't touch that line, so you'll still be able to log in through the serial port.

If there are still some messages getting through, you should redirect the console, passing something like `console=ttyS0` from the bootloader to the kernel. Exactly how it is done varies from system to system, refer to your board and bootloader documentation.